# XSL: Getting text values that contain any words in separate nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to get the text in `<line>`if the text contain any words in `<vehicleType>` and `<color>`. I also need to count how many words in `<vehicleType>`and `<color>` were contained in `<description>`. Is it possible to do using XSL(version=1.0)?

The output should look like:

```
Vehicle type (4)
This vehicle is a white <font color="red">compact car</font>.
This vehicle is a orange <font color="red">minivan</font>.
This vehicle is a red <font color="red">sedan</font>.
This vehicle is a yellow <font color="red">truck</font>.

Color (4)
This vehicle is a <font color="red">white</font> compact car.
This vehicle is a <font color="red">red</font> sedan.
This vehicle is a <font color="red">yellow</font> truck.
This vehicle is a <font color="red">yellow</font> crossover.
```

Here is the simplified xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test9.xsl"?>
<items>
    <vehicleTypes>
     <vehicleType>truck</vehicleType>
     <vehicleType>compace</vehicleType>
     <vehicleType>car</vehicleType>
     <vehicleType>sedan</vehicleType>
     <vehicleType>minivan</vehicleType>
    </vehicleTypes>
    <colors>
     <color>red</color>
     <color>yellow</color>
     <color>blue</color>
     <color>white</color>
     <color>purple</color>
     <color>gold</color>
     <color>silver</color>
    </colors>
    <item>
        <description>
            <p>
                <line>
                    This vehicle is a white compact car.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This vehicle is a orange minivan.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This vehicle is a red sedan.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This vehicle is a yellow truck.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This vehicle is a yellow crossover.
                </line>
            </p>
        </description>
    </item>
</items>
```

Answer (score 0):

To test whether any of the comma-separated values in 'vehicleType' or 'color' occur in the current element as whitespace or punctuation-delimited words or phrases, I'd write something like this (not tested):

```
<xsl:variable name="needles.vT" as="xs:string"
     select="tokenize(/items/vehicleType,',')"/>
<xsl:variable name="needles.c" as="xs:string"
     select="tokenize(/items/color,',')"/>
<xsl:variable name="haystack" as="xs:string"
     select="concat(' ',
                    normalize-space(
                      translate(.,
                         ' .,;:!?()-=+',
                         '            '),
                    ' ')"/>
<xsl:if test="some $needle in ($needles.vT, $needles.c)
              satisfies contains($haystack, 
                          concat(' ', $needle, ' ')">
  ... code for magic-word-found case ...
</xsl:if>
```

There may be more elegant ways to do it.

To get a count of the number of vehicleType and color needles in the haystack, I'd use something like

```
count($needles.vT[contains($haystack, concat(' ', ., ' '))])
count($needles.c[contains($haystack, concat(' ', ., ' '))])
```

In XSLT 1.0, I'd write a recursive template that works through the list of terms, peeling off the first term, adding one to an accumulator if it matches, and recurring on the rest of the list of terms.  The general form would be

```
<xsl:template name="countHits">
  <xsl:param name="needles"/><!--* terms to seek *-->
  <xsl:param name="haystack"/><!--* where to seek them *-->
  <xsl:param name="accumulator" select="0"/>
    <!--* number of hits so far *-->

  <xsl:variable name="needle">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($needles, ',')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($needles, ',')"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$needles"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="normalize-space($needles) = ''">
      <xsl:value-of select="$accumulator"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains($haystack, concat(' ', $needle, ' ')">
      <xsl:call-template name="countHits">
        <xsl:with-param name="needles"
          select="substring-after($needles, ',')"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="haystack"
          select="$haystack"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="accumulator"
          select="1 + $accumulator"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="countHits">
        <xsl:with-param name="needles"
          select="substring-after($needles, ',')"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="haystack"
          select="$haystack"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="accumulator"
          select="$accumulator"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>        
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I assume you can work out how to prepare the initial value of $haystack and how to call the template.

If you have any control over the form of the XML, you might consider changing 'vehicleType' and 'color' to put separate values in separate elements, thus:

```
<colors>
  <color>red</color>
  <color>yellow</color>
  <color>blue</color>
  <color>white</color>
  <color>purple</color>
  <color>gold</color>
  <color>silver</color>
</colors>
```

Then the test becomes something like the following (with $haystack defined as above):

```
<xsl:variable name="colorcount"
     select="count(/items/colors/color
             [contains($haystack, concat(' ', ., ' ')])"/>
```

and similarly for vehicleType.

Comment: Thanks @Sperberg-McQueen. I do have control over the XML and changed 'vehecleType' and 'color' as you suggested (see above). But, I couldn't get it to work. I'm new to XSL, and would you mind posting the entire xsl? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Actually, yes I would mind.  No offense, but my goal in this and most other answers is to show questioners how to help themselves and help them see  what topics they might want to learn about in order to solve their problem.  I avoid handing out completed solutions, because they aren't as effective in help questioners learn.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your help.